# How to validate single element in JQuery unobstrusive validation and JQuery Validate in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

Assumptions:

1. I have JQuery Unobstrusive validation and JQuery validate working fine in my ASP.NET MVC 5.2
2. Usual validation by clicking submit button is working fine.
3. I am using ASP.NET MVC Validation Summary to display the errors.

Now, when I try to call the single element validation using the below method:

```
form.validate().element(txtPostalCode)
```

Problems occur:

1. No error message displayed in Validation Summary when validation is failed.
2. When the validation is successful, I keep getting this error from unobstrusive validation.

> ```
> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attr' of undefined
> ```

To dig further in the bold code:

```
function onSuccess(error) {  // 'this' is the form element
    var container = error.data("unobtrusiveContainer"),
        **replaceAttrValue = container.attr("data-valmsg-replace"),**
```

Any idea on how to achieve this? Basically what I wanna do is to validate one element, and display the error in validation summary if any.

Thanks!

Comment: just to clarify, you are giving it like this form.validate().element('#txtPostalCode') instead of form.validate().element(txtPostalCode). right?

Comment: Yes, thanks for your interest. txtPostalCode is $("#txtPostalCode") stored in that variable.

Comment: have you tried $("#txtPostalCode").valid() ? however they both should work but still.. a hit and try

Comment: It works if your have individual validation messages - for example `@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.txtPostalCode)`

Comment: Try what @Shiv is suggesting.  Attach the `.valid()` method to the element...  `$("#txtPostalCode").valid()`.

Comment: I have tried what @Shiv suggested. It doesn't work. Html.ValidationMessageFor has already been implemented in MVC too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I did it. It solved my problem. So basically,

1. I put custom showErrors methods to suit my needs.
2. Somehow by doing point no 1 above, I would disrupt the usual behaviour of unobstrusive validation on the validation summary, so I need to reset the settings to default.

I am open for more elegant solution, but the codes below suits my needs.

Thanks! Hopefully, it helps!

```
var valSummary = $(".validation-summary");
var settings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
var ulSummary = valSummary.find("ul");
ulSummary.empty();

settings.showErrors = $.noop();
settings.showErrors = function (errorMap, errorList) {
    for (var i = 0; i < errorList.length; i++) {
        var liControl = $("<li />", {
            "text": errorList[i].message
         });

        var checkDuplicate = ulSummary.filter(function (idx, elem) {
            return $.trim($(elem).html()) === $.trim(liControl.html());
         });

        if (checkDuplicate.length === 0) {
            ulSummary.append(liControl);
        }
    }
    valSummary.show();
}

if (txtPostalCode.valid() && txtUnitNo.valid()) {
    valSummary.hide();
    RefreshValidationRules(); 
}
else {
    settings.showErrors = $.noop();
    return;
}

function RefreshValidationRules() {
    $("form").removeData("validator");
    $("form").removeData("unobtrusiveValidation");
    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("form");
    UnsetFocusInvalid();
}

function UnsetFocusInvalid() {
    var settings = $.data($('form')[0], 'validator').settings;
    settings.focusInvalid = false;
    settings.onfocusout = $.noop();
}
```